# Script to get a value from JSON embedded in XML

Tags: xml, json, ssis

Does anyone know how I can get a value from JSON embedded in XML and assign it to a variable in SSIS?

I have a job that creates XML with a JSON value like the following:

```
<string>
{"result_code":1,"result_message":"All calling list successfully retrieved records number","total_records":0,"total_processed":0,"total_excluded":0,"ResultCSV":null,"number_callinglist_records":6015}
</string>
```

Below is the script that I use to get the `"number_calling_list"` value from the embedded JSON and assign it to a string variable:

```
Dim totalCount As String = ""
If FileContents.Contains("number_callinglist_records") = True Then
    totalCount = Dts.Variables("number_callinglist_records").Value
End If


If FileContents.Contains("number_callinglist_records") = True Then
    EmailMessage = "List count has been successfully, see attached file for details " + totalCount
Else : EmailMessage = "List count has been failed, please see attachment for details"
```

It doesn't work, though, and displays the following error message when I run it:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The element
>   cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to
>   retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution
>   of the package and the element is not there.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can get the `"number_callinglist_records"` value from the embedded JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dts.Variables` reference looks wrong. I would change:

```
Dts.Variables("number_callinglist_records").Value
```

to

```
Dts.Variables("User::number_callinglist_records").Value
```